# Whats wrong with my javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, string, object, integer

I have a javascript "object." Im using the word object to make things easier.  Which is here:

```
var character = {
    name: "",
    myClass: "",
    health: 20,
    maxHealth: 20,
};
```

Say i have a game, and the game has fights, and after each fight you gain a health point.  which is done with:

```
character.maxHealth += 1;
```

However...  When i tried to do this, i ended up getting 201 as the maxHealth or 2032 or 203232 or whatever number i wanted to add to the max health was just adding as if it was a string.  through my eyes in looks like an integer to me but i must be mistaken.  if anyone can give me a hand it would be really appreciated.  That is an example of what i have.  the actual code is:

```
var character = {
name: "",
myClass: "",
health: 20,
maxHealth: 20,
stamina: 10,
maxStamina: 10,
mana: 5,
maxMana: 5,
physStrength: 3,
minAttack: 0,
mentStrength: 3,
physDefense: 3,
mentDefense: 3,
exp: 0,
punch: function() {
  toggleAttackButtons(0);
  this.minAttack = this.physStrength/3;
  var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.physStrength) + this.minAttack;
  addString("You punched and did " + damage + " damage.");
  myEnemy.health -= damage;
  updateStats();
  setTimeout(function(){
      myEnemy.attack();
      toggleAttackButtons(1);
      updateStats();
      }, 1000);
},
kick: function(){
  toggleAttackButtons(0);
  this.minAttack = this.physStrength/3;
  var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.physStrength) + this.minAttack;
  addString("You kicked and did " + damage + " damage.");
  myEnemy.health -= damage
  updateStats();
  setTimeout(function(){
      myEnemy.attack();
      toggleAttackButtons(1);
      updateStats();
      }, 1000);
},
};
```

and this is where im incrementing the number:

```
var updateStats = function() {
  document.getElementById("charHealth").innerHTML = "Health: " + character.health + " / " + character.maxHealth;
  document.getElementById("enemHealth").innerHTML = "Health: " + myEnemy.health + " / " + myEnemy.maxHealth;
  if(myEnemy.health <= 0){
    myEnemy.health = 0;
    character.maxHealth += 1;
    removeFightScreen(1);
  }
  if(character.health <= 0){
    removeFightScreen(2);
  }
};
```

I understand the object is messy i plan on rewriting it in the future to be a lot more efficient.  im just roughing it up right now.

Comment: Based on your code and sample above, it'll work. You have to verify tho that you're actually incrementing a number. And that is an actual object, FYI :D - You can always cast a number just to be sure: `character.maxHealth += +1;`

Comment: The code as it is works for me. Are you sure it's the same as what's not working for you?

Comment: Somewhere you're making one or the other a string, there is no other explanation!

Comment: i figured it would work but thats the output im getting =/  i guess i can try and run a few more tracers.  and ya i know its an object but i was trying to make room for the people who might disagree considering its javascript.

Comment: my actual object is more in depth but i searched through and there isnt any errors

Comment: At the point just before trying to increment place this line `console.log(typeof character.maxHealth);` and note the output. http://jsfiddle.net/8zx43gsq/

Comment: The problem isn't "object" or "javascript".  The problem is that you really have `maxHealth: "20"` or `maxHealth += "1";` (note the extra quotes).  (Which I guess is a problem with javascript.)  The reason you're getting down votes is that you've hidden the actual problem by not copying your actual code.

Comment: i wll try the typeof function thank you.  i also just editted to contain real code.  thank you again.

Comment: So now youve shown us the *real* code, which is a start - but you've not pointed out where this problem is occuring, so I need to trawl through trying to locate. Part of getting a good answer is asking a good question!

Comment: the problem is the same.  any of the keys that have integer values do it.  given this i figured a small example would be easier.  i also couldnt find any potential bugs in the object code that might convert the numbers to strings on accident

Comment: You have included the code for your object but not the code which is causing the issue. The code where this `character.maxHealth += 1;` is happening

Comment: i have used the typeof function and it returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the answer.  Im sorry for my lack of code evidence, however it contains cookies, so when i write the cookies using the character stats like health and maxHealth, they end up being converted into strings to fit the cookie.  Therefore i need to convert them back to integers.  thank you guys for your help.  Next time i will add in all the code i just felt that being there was several hundred lines of code i didnt want to go through it all.